# Problem Adding VBScript Into JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using a Datepicker on my site and want the current day (selected on page load) to advance one day forward at 2pm.

```
$(function() {
var dd = 0
var dsc = new Date();
if (dsc.getHours() > 14) {
dd = dd + 1; // go one day in the future
}
```

Works perfectly but this uses the local time on the users machine.

So I tried this.

```
$(function() {       
var dd = 0
var dsc = ('<%= currentHour %>');
if (dsc > 14) {
dd = dd + 1; // go one day in the future
}
```

The currentHour gets it's value from

```
Dim currentHour
currentHour = Hour(Now)
```

But this won't work. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are declaring `currentHour` on the server side and that it outputs correctly in the JavaScript fragment you posted.

You don't need to put the `currentHour` in quotes and parentheses.

```
$(function() {       
  var dd = 0
  var dsc = <%= currentHour %>;
  if (dsc > 14) {
    dd = dd + 1; // go one day in the future
  }
}
```

You don't need the `dsc` variable either:

```
$(function() {       
  var dd = 0
  if (<%= currentHour %> > 14) {
    dd = dd + 1; // go one day in the future
  }
}
```

**Edit:** (following the comments)

The <%= %> syntax is an asp feature that will only be processed when in an ASP page. If this is in a static JS file, it will remain as it is and not be processed.

Comment: Thanks Oded, tried your code and it crashed the calendar, changed (<%= currentHour %> > 14) to ('<%= currentHour %>' > 14) and calendar back, but still won't add a day on.

Comment: Where is `currentHour` created? In client side or server side VBScript?

Comment: And the JS file is on the same page or in a JS file?

Comment: That's your problem. The JS file will not be processed by the asp engine, so <%= %> never get processed. You need that JS inline on the page, on in an asp include.

Comment: That's fixed it, moved the JS inline and it works a dream. Thanks Oded.
BTW, I did still need to leave the '<%=%>' for it to display correctly.